# Spark: Create temporary table by executing sql query on temporary tables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jenkins, jdbc

I am using Spark and I would like to know: how to create temporary table named C by executing sql query on tables A and B ?

```
sqlContext
   .read.json(file_name_A)
   .createOrReplaceTempView("A")

sqlContext
   .read.json(file_name_B)
   .createOrReplaceTempView("B")

val tableQuery = "(SELECT A.id, B.name FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.fk_id) C"

sqlContext.read
   .format(SQLUtils.FORMAT_JDBC)
   .options(SQLUtils.CONFIG())
   .option("dbtable", tableQuery)
   .load()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to save your results as temp table

```
tableQuery .createOrReplaceTempView("dbtable")
```

Permanant storage on external table you can use JDBC

```
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
prop.setProperty("user", "vaquar")
prop.setProperty("password", "khan") 
 
//jdbc mysql url - destination database is named "temp"
val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/temp"
 
//destination database table 
val dbtable = "sample_data_table"
 
//write data from spark dataframe to database
df.write.mode("append").jdbc(url, dbtable, prop)
```

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#saving-to-persistent-tables

Answer (score 2):

```
sqlContext.read.json(file_name_A).createOrReplaceTempView("A")
sqlContext.read.json(file_name_B).createOrReplaceTempView("B")
val tableQuery = "(SELECT A.id, B.name FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.fk_id) C"
sqlContext.sql(tableQuery).createOrReplaceTempView("C")
```

Try the above code it will work.

Comment: Your answer is working, unfortunatly I can not use sqlContext.sql since it will not execute the entire request in the database. Indeed, sqlContext.sql can split the query into two select and then execute the join on diferrents worker. In my case, the workers have not enough memory to handle it and they crash...